# how to change ngBootstrap datepicker border-radius

Tags: css, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I want to set the border-radius of the ngBoostrap datepicker to 0.

CSS:

```
[_nghost-c9] {
   border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ngb-datepicker _ngcontent-c7="" tabindex="0" _nghost-c9="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
</ngb-datepicker>
```

I don't want to change any code of ngBootstrap. Is there a method on how to override this css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [Example Link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32pprz)

add class to `ngb-datepicker` called `c-datepicker`

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next" class="c-datepicker"></ngb-datepicker>
```

add css

```
.c-datepicker{
  border-radius:0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like below

```
ngb-datepicker[_nghost-c9] {
  border-radius: 0.50rem;
}
```

this should work

you can even add any parent class,tag etc to your selector

```
div [_nghost-c9]{}
```

or add class to your element call it like

```
.my-class[_nghost-c9]{}
```